# Module vs. Module Instance in BEM, SMACSS and OOCSS

Tags: oocss, bem, smacss

Most CSS methodologies have the concept of reusable modules - BEM calls them blocks whereas SMACSS and OOCSS calls them modules. All of them recommend creating the modules with a class, e.g.

```
.room {}
```

Now if I have two or more instances of rooms in my HTML markup, how do I distinguish between them? I have been doing something like this:

```
<div class="room room1"></div>
<div class="room room2"></div>
```

But I am not finding the concept of module identity in any of the methodologies. I only see the concept of module modifiers or sub-classing, i.e. creating modules with extended look and/or behavior, e.g. `room-kitchen`. But that's not what I am doing here - all I am doing is creating two instance of the same module and using the identities to say place them at different locations. I don't see any of the methodologies talking about module instances and how to name them. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! So this is a little hard to answer because I don't know exactly what you are styling. But using the example about with BEM you would do:

```
<div class="room room--right"></div>
<div class="room room--left"></div>
```

Double hyphens indicate a modifier in BEM syntax.

I would further modify the code above this way:

```
<div class="room--right"></div>
<div class="room--left"></div>
```

And the css would be:

```
[class*=room] {
  ...base styles here...
}

.room--right {
  ...specific right styles here...
}

.room--left {
  ...specific left styles here...
}
```

Good luck! Stay awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly all named methodologies, in case of CSS, its just naming convention, just a system of class naming to keep structure clean.

in **BEM** there is modificators e.g

```
<span class="block_modificator_value"> some </span>
```

in **SMACSS** - sub-class

```
<span class="module-sub-some"> some </span>
```

So to get the correct module you can use any of this system to add some concrete information to determine it:

**BEM**

```
<span class="block_modificator_value block_id_123"> some </span>
```

**SMACSS**

```
<span class="module-sub-some module-id-123"> some </span>
```

In CSS its only way to identify modules instances.

If you interested in identifying modules via JS. You can use some framework like Angular or

Marionette - to hook up HTML markup with View abstraction. In this case you can avoid using subclassing as you can work with View.

I can share with you some Marionette\ Backbone examples if you interested in.